# Saving breakpoints after re-sourcing binary

Tags: c++, c, lldb

I have a small work environment related doubt. I am analyzing a binary in LLDB and sometimes, I need to make some changes in the code and re-compile it. And then re-source the new binary into LLDB for further analysis.

Currently, I am doing this

1. Inside LLDB, use `shell <shell-command>` to compile the code.
2. Use `file <binary>` to reload the binary.

But in this way, I am losing the breakpoints. So, is there any way I can save breakpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things.

First off, if you are recompiling the binary at the same path you used for your current lldb target, then you don't need to make a new target.  lldb will notice the file has changed when you do `run` read in the new binary & debug information, reset the breakpoints, etc.

But if there are other reasons why you need to make a new target, lldb has `breakpoint write` and `breakpoint read` commands that allow you to serialize the breakpoints to a file and then read them back into a new target.